# What to do when I abandon a question?

Tags: discussion, abandonment

What should I do?

1. Just leave it without accepted answer; or
2. Accept answer that seems most useful without actual verifying it; or
3. Vote to close; or
4. Convert to community wiki or something else.

If I "Just leave", it would be `Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?`, if I just accept something, it would be an illusion that I've deployed this answer and it actually helped.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54737/i-no-longer-need-an-answer-to-a-question-what-should-i-do-to-the-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you abandoning it?

Anyway, I'd just accept the highest voted answer by the community if you just don't care anymore.

Comment: Because of 1. I stop interesting about the problem; 2. I found better entirely other way (unrelated to the question); 3. It became clear that the question is flawed and don't worth being answered.

Comment: @Vi, if it's unanswered, you can just delete it (Best option IMO), if it has answers with upvotes, accept the highest rated one

Comment: If number 2 is the case, leave a note or answer to that effect on the question. Often times finding another way (even when it is not directly an answer to the question) will help others who have a similar problem. In the case of 1 and 3, I'd remove the question.

Answer (score 2):

- Post your new solution as an answer.
- Close it when your solution does not apply to the question anymore, and explain why.

You choose.

Comment: Solution can be absolutely outside the scope of the question? Example question: "How to download a file from qqqqq.com?". And "answer" would be "quit wanting to watch that movie and therefore don't download" or "read the text version of it" or even "you can find information you want in Wikipedia".

Answer (score -1):

I would first edit the question saying something like "I'm abandoning the question, don't bother to answer anymore".

Also, if no good answers were posted add your own answer and accept if you're worried about acceptance rate.