# Should I delete old questions that never received an answer?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, self-delete

I have asked a few questions that never received an answer. For some of those I have moved on, and don't really care any more, if I ever will get an answer. Should I delete those questions?

Comment: Not a good idea. See: [I apparently got question-banned for deleting some of my old, zero-upvoted questions.  Is there a better way to handle these?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91956)

Comment: Further, old, unanswered, zero-upvote questions eventually get deleted automatically.

Comment: See also: [What should be done with my own old forgotten questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155695)

Comment: See also: [I no longer need an answer to a question; what should I do to the question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54737)

Answer (score 8):

On the contrary, you would have somehow either solved those issues or found workarounds to get past them. If nobody has answered them till now, then you should post your own solutions or workarounds as answers. This will create value for the entire community moving ahead.

Stack Exchange encourages [self-answered questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: What I meant by "moved on" is that those questions where asked in a context of projects I am no longer involved in. I never found an answer myself.

Comment: Also, deleting too many questions might trigger a question ban; although I don't know if this holds when the questions have no answers.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Ah! Good to know. I guess if those questions don't hurt me, I'll just let them be.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I dont think the question ban gets triggered in this case. It is usually in the case of closed/downvoted questions being deleted.